# Python - Modulus format variable

Tags: python, modulus

When I type the following into Notepad++ as Python code:

```
days = "Mon"

print "Here are the days: %s ". % days
```

I get this output in Windows Powershell:

```
File "ex9exp.py", line 4
print "Here are the days: %s ". % days
```

I am at a loss as to why this is happening.

I intend for the output of

```
print "Here are the days: %s ". % days
```

to be

```
Here are the days: Mon
```

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Why the dot after the string? Also how are you running the code?

Comment: If you are getting a syntax error remove the . after the string "Here are the days: %s "

Comment: Ah ok - just removed the dot and it worked!

Thanks. Am quite new to this. If you could reply in a comment explaining why the dot led to it not working that would be very grand! 

Am a beginner and am learning this as I go along.

Comment: OK @Raz, I explained the problem in the answer. Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The . after the string is an operator used in some languages like PHP to append strings, but it does not work in Python, so a code like this:

```
days = "Mon"

print "Here are the days: %s ". % days
```

Produces the following output:

```
   File "h.py", line 3
     print "Here are the days: %s ". % days
                                     ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Letting you know the compiler/interpreter was not expecting a ".".

The problem can be fixed removing the ., like this:

```
days = "Mon"

print "Here are the days: %s " % days
```

It will work that way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the syntax of the `print` function you are using is wrong.

```
>>> days = "Mon"
>>> 
>>> print "Here are the days: %s ". % days   
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "Here are the days: %s ". % days   
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Remove the `.`. and try

```
>>> print "Here are the days: %s " % days   
Here are the days: Mon
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `+` to append strings

```
print "Here are the days: " + days
```

will work